# achartengine cause null pointer

Tags: android, achartengine

I have issue regarding package org.achartengine (both available versions 1.2.0 and 1.1.0).

In my application I call new activity, pass on parameters and then fill data for graph.

All this is in same class:

```
private void showChart(CustomerTransactionModel ctm, String title) {
    try {
        if (ctm==null || ctm.getTransactionGroup()==null || 
                ctm.getTransactionGroup().getTransactionTemplate()==null || 
                ctm.getTransactionGroup().getTransactionTemplate().getAxisXProperty()==null ||
                ctm.getTransactionGroup().getTransactionTemplate().getAxisYProperty()==null ||
                ctm.getTransactionGroup().getTransactions()==null) {
            return;
        }
        String xKey=ctm.getTransactionGroup().getTransactionTemplate().getAxisXProperty();
        String yKey=ctm.getTransactionGroup().getTransactionTemplate().getAxisYProperty();

        ArrayList<String[]> v = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        for (Transaction tran : ctm.getTransactionGroup().getTransactions()) {
            if (tran!=null && tran.getServiceData()!=null) {
                Map<Object, Object> serviceData = tran.getServiceData();

                if (serviceData.containsKey(xKey) && serviceData.containsKey(yKey)) {
                    String[] add=new String[2];
                    add[0]=serviceData.get(xKey).toString();
                    add[1]=serviceData.get(yKey).toString();

                    v.add(add);
                }
            }
        }
        if (!v.isEmpty()) {
            openChartDialog(v, title, xKey, yKey);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
    }
}

private void openChartDialog(ArrayList<String[]> v, String title, String xLabel, String yLabel) {
    try {
        Object[] objects=new Object[4];
        objects[0]=xLabel;
        objects[1]=yLabel;
        objects[2]=title;
        objects[3]=v;
        OpeningChartTask task = new OpeningChartTask();
        task.doInBackground(objects);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
    }
}

private class OpeningChartTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        String xLabel=(String) params[0];
        String yLabel=(String) params[1];
        String title=(String) params[2];
        ArrayList<String[]> v=(ArrayList<String[]>) params[3];

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ChartDialogActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("xLabel", xLabel);
        intent.putExtra("yLabel", yLabel);
        intent.putExtra("title", title);
        intent.putExtra("values", v);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        return null;
    }
}
```

So far so good. In on create, I read those data (they are set successfuly) and then call method openBarChart() that contains this:

```
private void openBarChart() {
    // Create XY Series for X Series.
    XYSeries xSeries = new XYSeries("X series");
    // Adding data to the X Series.
    for (int i = 0; i < _data.size(); i++) {
        xSeries.add(Double.parseDouble(_data.get(i)[0]),
                Double.parseDouble(_data.get(i)[1]));
    }

    // Create XYSeriesRenderer to customize XSeries
    XYSeriesRenderer Xrenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    Xrenderer.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    Xrenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(20);
    Xrenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.DIAMOND);
    Xrenderer.setDisplayChartValues(false);
    Xrenderer.setLineWidth(2);
    Xrenderer.setFillPoints(true);

    // Create XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to customize the whole chart
    final XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

    mRenderer.setChartTitle("X Vs Y Chart");
    mRenderer.setXTitle("X Values");
    mRenderer.setYTitle("Y Values");
    mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);
    mRenderer.setXLabels(0);
    mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true);
    mRenderer.setAntialiasing(true);
    mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    mRenderer.setBarWidth(20);
    mRenderer.setScale((float) 0.3);

    mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);

    mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);

    for (int i = 0; i < _data.size(); i++) {
        mRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, _data.get(i)[0]);
    }

    // Adding the XSeriesRenderer to the MultipleRenderer.
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(Xrenderer);

    LinearLayout chart_container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chartLayoutTest);

    // Create a Dataset to hold the XSeries.
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

    // Add X series to the Dataset.
    dataset.addSeries(xSeries);

    // Creating an intent to plot line chart using dataset and
    // multipleRenderer
    final GraphicalView mChart;
    mChart = (GraphicalView) ChartFactory.getBarChartView(this, dataset,
            mRenderer, BarChart.Type.DEFAULT);

    // Add the graphical view mChart object into the Linear layout .
    chart_container.removeAllViews();
    chart_container.addView(mChart);
    if (mChart != null) {
        mChart.repaint();
    }
}
```

This method also survive but when it should be shown on screen it throws error and app die.

stacktrace is below:

```
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461): [uncaughtException] > ************ CAUSE OF ERROR ************
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461): 
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at java.util.TreeMap$BoundedMap.<init>(TreeMap.java:1115)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at java.util.TreeMap.headMap(TreeMap.java:713)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at  org.achartengine.model.XYSeries.getRange(XYSeries.java:310)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at org.achartengine.chart.XYChart.draw(XYChart.java:261)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at org.achartengine.GraphicalView.onDraw(GraphicalView.java:181)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13826)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13710)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2988)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2858)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13829)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13710)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2988)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2858)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13829)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13710)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2988)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2858)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13708)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2988)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2858)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13708)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2988)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2858)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13829)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2458)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawSoftware(ViewRootImpl.java:2382)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2275)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2143)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1954)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1108)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4491)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:755)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:585)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:555)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:741)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4949)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1043)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810)
E/ExceptionHandler( 8461):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Oh and this, I did the work and checked content of those .java files and found couple of "tweaks" but I guess it's me that working something wrong here. If I make new project I can normally use this jar, the only difference is that previously I imported jar but now I'm calling this jar with maven pom file (I have my own repository but it should work ok anyway).

Thank you!

*****SOLUTION FOUND*****

In class org.achartengine.model.XYSeries I created simple Comparator and passed it to both TreeMap constructors. Then I changed constructor in org.achartengine.util.IndexXYMap to accept coparator and passed on to super(comparator).

I don't know exactly yet why this happened in one project and it didn't in previous so I'll leave question open, if anyone has explanation for this.

Thank you @keshav for your efforts.

Comment: Are u using TreeMap? If yes , show that part .

Comment: No, I'm just filling data via xSeries.add method. Same example as I used here works on different project.

Comment: what is the value of _data ?

Comment: It is ArrayList<String[]> where I put 2 or 3 strings per list item, depends on what should be shown.

Comment: Values are doubles as strings. This code is ok and does not throw any error. When draw method is called for chart (after all data and renderers are already set), then it throws it.

Comment: Your method openBarChart() is working correctly. Can you show how u r assigning values to _data ?Either may be error is because of some other part of code .

Comment: Added methods in question. I don't think more should be provided but could be if needed just it's a lot of code to show...

Comment: Are you getting _data in ChartDialogActivity ? Bcoz it seems you are adding array by put extra that will not work in this way .

Comment: I get all data inside, checked it with debugging. Also on that line where it throws error in XYSeries.getRange() it shows that I have values inside.

Comment: @keshav, I found solution. Look at last edit of question.